# Dev C, math.h problems

Tags: c++, c, imagemagick, dev-c++, math.h

I just installed devcpp, and am attempting to make sure it is working.  When I ran into compile errors surrounding math.h.  I am using a couple of simple programs that have been compiled and run before, so there shouldn't be any problems there.  I would normally use cmath instead, but I need to use Magick++ for a few things as well, which uses math.h.  Has anybody run into this?  Know of a work around?

The errors are

Line 594 of math.h   expected ')' before '(' token

Line 594 of math.h   expected ',' or ';' before '(' token

'abs' undeclared

line 594

```
 extern double __cdecl nearbyint (double);
```

and in context

```
/* 7.12.9.2 Double in C89 */
extern float __cdecl floorf (float);
extern long double __cdecl floorl (long double);

/* 7.12.9.3 */
extern double __cdecl nearbyint (double);
extern float __cdecl nearbyintf (float);
extern long double __cdecl nearbyintl (long double);
```

Comment: where did you download devc++ from? is it the latest version?orwell devc++ or bloodshed devc++?

Comment: I have tried both bloodshed v. 4.9.9.2, and orwell v. 5.4.1.  The result is the same with each.

Comment: why cant you try code::blocks? its better and free

Comment: I have tried code blocks as well with the same result.  Everything that requires math.h results in an error.

Comment: ok then post the code where  it gives error. it might not be IDE problem.

Comment: even something as simple as this gives an error
`#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  int n, result;
 
  printf("Enter an integer to calculate it's absolute value\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);
 
  result = abs(n);
 
  printf("Absolute value of %d = %d\n", n, result);
 
  return 0;
}`

sorry about the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help at all - http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/5207/

I'm also using Dev C++ right now and can't stand it, but it is required for a class.  Is there a reason you can't just use Visual Studio Express, it is also a free download -

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34673

Comment: I can't use Visual Studio Express.  Imagemagick requires a build, and VSE doesn't have the required libraries to build it.